# In git, how did I put myself in a situation where there were unstaged changes that didn't need to be committed after I added them?

Tags: git, intellij-idea

I'm very new to git, and I'm pushing with git-svn.

My ide (intellij idea) said everything was committed.  But "git status" said I had "Changes not staged for commit".  I added those files, and now a "git status" doesn't mention them at all.  Shouldn't it say they're staged for commit?  I expected to have to do a "git commit" next.  Can someone explain how this happened and why it worked this way?

Comment: That behavior is incorrect. I'd be more inclined to believe what the command line tools are telling you. Try [git fsck](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-fsck.html) to see if there isn't a more serious problem with your repository.

Comment: that output this: `$ git fsck\n
dangling blob 68b0b4416fbeafe0c5cdeb3e7114dfdb734db1eb\n
dangling blob 5ee15c66ee854f8750717d930e4ff7d7f622dd4d`

Comment: @PeterLundgren those dangling blobs seem like a class I deleted then added later.  I'd like for them to be ignored.  Still, I wonder if those dangling blobs will actually cause a problem or are relevant to this question?

Comment: No, dangling blobs are to be expected. If `git fsck --no-dangling` is empty than your repository's integrity is fine. I suspect intellij has the wrong idea about the state of your repository somehow. Try restarting it or making a new project with a copy of the repo and see if the problem persists?